# Node.JS running a Node-Msql query again with out stopping node.js script

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I need to re-run a node.js query, to get the latest entries. this is what I have tried so far.

```
 setTimeout(function() { 

connection.query('SELECT *  FROM News ORDER BY Content DESC LIMIT 1', function(err, rows, fields){
var News = rows[0].Content;
}, 2000);
```

I would have thought this would have worked, running the query again when the timer reaches 0, I know 2 seconds is a bit short, it was just for testing purposes.

Its all part of a express.js web server, when I navigate to the page it doesn't update the text with the newest entry. What is the best way to deal with this? I have  to restart the script to get the latest entries, I would like to do it with out having to restart the script.

Comment: can you provide a few more details? the query is executes async, so you'll need to be sure you are properly handling that for your req/resp as well as this query. The setTimeout will not prevent the response being returned to the client.

Comment: What kind of details? I just need to know how I can re-run a mysql query.

Comment: Are you running the same query twice and using the setTimeout in an attempt to delay the second run?

Comment: no, setTimeout is my attempt to re run the query again when it runs out

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is that You need to do a new request/response.

The setTimeout should be set in the browser not in node.js .

SO after n seconds you want, you do a new request/response and then doing a new query into the Mysql DB.

Now, in the other hand might be we have a cached resulSet. To avoid caching try varying your query select text. For example write it in lowercase

```
select *  from news order by content desc limit 1
```

Comment: I use the News variable for displaying the result, its updated once when the  database is queried, but i can't do more then 1 mysql query in the same code?

Comment: What I'm trying to say You is that the response will be sent before the second query runs... so the response is related to the first call not the second... The setTimeout won't stop the next lines for running.

Comment: I am using the timer so that when it runs out, it will re-run the query? I'm confused what you are saying.

Comment: @scottjustin5000 is saying You the same. Simply understand or research more about setTimeout... is not a wait() method like in linux. There are other methods in javascript for wait... try for example for(;;){dosomething;}

Comment: I am not waiting, it was when it goes to 0, it would re-run the code?

Comment: I think your query is being cached